# Missing Standard Library Crosscompiling for aarch64 Android

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, arm64

On my host system (Ubuntu, 64Bit) I use `gcc/g++` compilers to crosscompile my library for my Android app (arm64-v8a). On calling functions from my App I receive messages that libraries like `libc.so.6` or `libstdc++.so.6` cannot be found.

Within my `/usr` directory I have an `aarch64-linux-gnu` folder containing `bin`, `include` and `lib` folders.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE android.toolchain.cmake)

project(testlibrary)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STYANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# find header & source
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_CPP "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER "src/*.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}  SHARED
  ${SOURCE_CPP}
  ${HEADER}
)

source_group("Header include" FILES ${HEADER})
source_group("Source src"     FILES ${SOURCE_CPP})
```

**android.toolchain.cmake:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "aarch64-linux-gnu-g++")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

The error messages are the following:

```
dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found: needed by /my/lib/path/testlib.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

or

```
dlopen failed: library "libstdc++.so.6" not found: needed by /my/lib/path/testlib.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

Do I have to set a Sysroot or other paths so my libraries are found within my toolchain file and which path(s) do I use?

**EDIT1:** Adding the `aarch64-linux-gnu` folder to my build directory and explicitly including

```
target_link_libraries($PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
# also any other lib, e.g. libstdc++.so, libc.so and libc.so.6 don't work
```

still results in the mentioned error message.

I made a minimal example of the error using the `.cpp` and `.hpp` files below which results in this case in `libc.so.6 not found`. Removing the malloc line also removes the error messages. Calling the testFunc also return the correct value to my App which I can display.
**src_file.cpp**

```
#include "header_file.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc
int testFunc_(){
  char* buffer;
  buffer = (char *) malloc (10);
  return 42;
}
```

**header_file.hpp**

```
extern "C" int testFunc_();
```

I also added the following lines to my `android.toolchain.cmake` file (I copied the folder from /usr/aarch64/linux-gnu/ to my build dir)

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)

set(LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

**EDIT2:**
On running `readelf -d 'path/to/lib'` I get the following (necessary I suppose) entries

```
Tag         Type            Name/Value
0x000...1   (NEEDED)        Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x000..1d   (RUNPATH)       Library runpath: [/home/username/Desktop/projectfolder/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib]
```

Adding the following line to my `CMakeLists.txt` (after removing the `RPATH` related stuff from my toolchain file or changing them also to `./`) should allow me to add the libraries right next to my `library.so` in the build folder (arm64-v8a).

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,./")
```

There is no `RPATH` tag. The `RUNPATH` entry is the location of my `.so.6` and `.so` files I copied from the `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` folder. I think my main problem is bundling the necessary libraries correctly within my application as David Grayson implicated.

**EDIT3:**
Running `file libc.so.6` also shows its an ELF 64-bit LSB shared object with ARM aarch64 architecture dynamically linked for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, stripped

**EDIT4:**
Within my `app/build.gradle` I have the following lines

```
if(isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
  externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-12",
      "APP_STL=c_++shared",
      "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=gcc", // was clang before
      "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
      "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
      "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=${reactNativeRoot}/ReactAndroid",
      "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=${reactNativeRoot}/ReactAndroid/build",
      "NODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules"
      cflags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
      cppFlags "-std=c++17", //maybe 11 here(?) tried out both my App and .so to 11 but also no success

      targets "myapp_appmodules"
    }
  }
}
```

and also

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libm.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libm.so.6'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libstdc++.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libstdc++.so.6'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc.so.6'
}
```

Am I probably using a wrong compiler/give the standalone toolchain within my ndk folder a try!

Comment: Why did you use an equal sign with LDFLAGS but not the other variables you are setting?

Comment: I saw it in another reply, also it seems not to make any difference as far as I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it changing my compilers (`CMAKE_C_COMPILER`  and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` ) within the toolchain file and leaving my **CMakeLists.txt** as it was in the first place.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/username/path/to/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/username/path/to/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang++)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/username/path/to/ndk)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

using Android API level 21.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to link those libraries statically into your executable (`-static` at link time might work) or you need to ship them with your executable and put them somewhere the executable will find them, like in the same directory.

I'm not very familiar with Android but there might also be a way to have the target Android system provide those libraries at run time, since they are very common and used widely.

Comment: Can I ```-static``` link dynamic libraries? Also I am building a dyn. library not an executable and I place the ```.so.6```, ```.so``` etc. files from my compilers lib folder right next to my library within Android ```arm64-v8a``` folder.